# Not receiving MMS messages from iPhones?

Tags: sms, mms, ios

Whenever someone with an iPhone sends me a text, I can't see it, and instead get a "Download" link...which always fails to download anything. Googling shows this is likely due to a non-standard feature iPhones implement, where if you send a text to multiple people, it sends an MMS message instead of an SMS message, and it seems the default text messaging app in Android doesn't support MMS messages.

Is there any way I can fix this on my end? Is there a setting I can change in Android to read MMS messages, or a different messaging app that support these?

Comment: Try Google Messenger. Download in the play store.

Comment: Have you tried understanding the issue already reported through other similar questions to this stackexchange? Here is a [query](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=mms+iphone+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1) to familiarize yourself. If, after trying the suggested (and sometimes accepted) answers, edit in the specifics of your problem that limits the differences, so a solution may be suggested.

Comment: @wbogacz, Thank you for that link. However, none of those answers are helpful, and the vast majority have no accepted solutions. What specifics should I add?

Comment: @esQmo, Tried it. I experience the same problem.